# Best way to extract content in Word document to SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, vba, import, ms-word, ssms

I have a question bank of 100,000 questions in the form of word documents. The questions are in text with some containing images. Is there any efficient way of extracting the questions one at a time (**including images**) and importing them into an SQL database? Would prefer not to have to convert the text to images as the questions may have to be edited. Thanks!

Comment: When you say SQL database, do you have any specific dbms in mind?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the prompt reply. The dbms used is MS SQL Server Management Studio 17.2. Upon closer look, some of the questions contain Word objects such as empty boxes. Pretty sure that is gonna complicate things... Would a VBA script still be the way to go?

Comment: I replaced some of the tags, to get better attention.

Comment: can you post a link to a screenshot of the word document with the paragraph marks and all the other formatting marks visible?  replace any private data if necessary, but keep the formatting exactly the same.

Comment: @jsotola here's a screenshot of the first page: https://imgur.com/a/FC3OB. The other pages do not contain the first 4 lines of text. Thanks!

Comment: the box in question #2 ... is that an image?

Comment: @jsotola It is a microsoft word object. Will it have to be converted to .jpg before being exported to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

here is a beginning

separates question number, question text, each answer number and each answer text

then it prints them in immediate window

please try it with one of your documents

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse()

    Dim rgx As Object
    Set rgx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    rgx.MultiLine = True
    rgx.Global = True
    rgx.pattern = "^[\s]+|[\s]+$"

    Dim s As String

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim qNum As Long
    Dim qest As String

    Dim aNum As Integer
    Dim answ As String

    Dim par As Paragraphs
    Set par = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    Dim p As Integer
    For p = 1 To par.Count
        s = rgx.Replace(par(p).Range.Text, "")                  ' trim whitespace (leading and trailing)
'        Debug.Print "--- "; s

        Select Case Left(s, 1)
            Case "0" To "9"                                     ' question found
                qNum = CDec(Split(s, ".")(0))                   ' number
                i = 1

                qest = rgx.Replace(Split(s, ".", 2)(1), "")     ' first line of text

                Do While True
                    s = rgx.Replace(par(p + i).Range.Text, "")  ' check for multiline question
                    If Len(s) > 0 Then
                        If Left(s, 1) = "(" Then
                            p = p + i - 1                       ' it is an answer line, so exit
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            qest = qest & vbNewLine & s         ' assemble multiline question
                        End If
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
                Loop

                Debug.Print vbNewLine; "question # "; qNum; vbTab; qest

            Case "("                                            ' answer found
                aNum = CDec(Mid(s, 2, 1))                       ' number
                answ = Split(s, ")", 2)(1)                      ' text
                Debug.Print "answer # "; aNum, answ
        End Select
    Next p


End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, am currently caught up with other projects. Thank you so much for sharing the code, will update on the progress as soon as I have time to continue on that project.